# Use of `do` construct in function arguments (macros)

Tags: elixir

I've just covered the basics of Elixir and decided to have some fun with metaprogramming. In the book by Chris McCord, there's the following example of defining our own `unless` construct:

```
defmodule ControlFlow do
  defmacro unless(expression, do: block) do
    quote do
      if !unquote(expression), do: unquote(block)
    end
  end
end
```

I can't seem to make the sense of the `unless(expression, do: block)` part. The only use I've encountered of the `do:` construct is when shortening the body of a function and compressing it into a single line. However, here, the block to the executed after `unless` is already part of the arguments to the function. How does the `do: block` part fit in here? Perhaps I'm just overlooking something really simple, but I'll be happy to have it pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do: block` in the function declaration is just simple pattern matching to easily extract the value passed to the keyword argument `:do`. It's equivalent to doing:

```
defmacro unless(expression, [do: block])
```

which is short for:

```
defmacro unless(expression, [{:do, block}])
```

and behaves just like you would expect it to:

```
iex(1)> [do: block] = [do: 123]
[do: 123]
iex(2)> block
123
```

You can also rewrite `unless` to not use pattern matching like this:

```
defmodule ControlFlow do
  defmacro unless(expression, args) do
    quote do
      if !unquote(expression), do: unquote(args[:do])
    end
  end
end
```

<sub>This is not completely equivalent to the original code as it'll silently ignore the absence of `do:` argument but it's easy to modify the code to support that.</sub>

Comment: Fabulous! And the `{:do, block}` thing is a tuple, I guess? If that's so, I don't recall tuples being accessed as `args[:do]`, supposing `arg = {:do, block}`. Or maybe I need to revisit the basic datatypes! :P Please help explain a little more.

Comment: `args[:do]` works because `args` is a _list_ of tuples where the first term is an atom, also known as Keyword Lists in Elixir: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Keyword.html.

Comment: Yup. Makes sense now! :-)